# Windows 10-Screen goes black momentarily when ever I right click anything

Tags: windows-10

I tried to open File Explorer from the task bar.The screen went black momentarily then the desktop came back but no File Explorer. I have Word & Excel on the Task Bar and they open properly. Pushing "Shift" & X at the same time gives me a list containing File Explorer. When I select anything on the list, the screen goes black momentarily but nothing opens. Whenever I right click anything on my desktop Same thing.
   If I open Word and Browse to a document and right click the document, Word stops working and I'm prompted to Close Program

Comment: Is the screen turning off and back on, or is Windows Explorer crashing and reloading? Try setting a background color to something other than black, and then observe if you can see this color while the taskbar and explorer are not visible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and still have the same problem. The screen is not turning off, just going black with all icons disappearing then re-appearing.   I get the same thing whenever I right click on anything, even in Safe Mode

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 probably needs some TLC, some introspection, and a little repair.

First, you'll need to use the System File Checker to check the system files:

1. Right-click on your start menu.
2. Click on Command Prompt (admin) (or Windows PowerShell (admin) if that is the option you have).
3. In the command window enter `sfc /scannow` and press the Enter key.
4. Let it finish.

If this fails to resolve the issue, proceed to the DISM commands:

1. Open the admin command prompt just like before.
2. Type `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and press the Enter key.
3. Let if finish.

If THIS doesn't resolve the issue then you'll need to use one of the Recovery options in Windows 10.

1. Open Settings, then Update & Security, then Recovery, and use one of the options there, most like Reset this PC.